# Getting 403 response at this specific URL

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to get the JSON from an API url, but I'm getting `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403`.

If I just put the link in the browser, it works fine. Here is the link (replace TOKEN with an access token): [API](http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/locale/3477/days/15?token=TOKEN)

I think the code is working, cause it works when I use the JSONPlaceHolder link: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/

My code:

```java
private static String streamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        String text = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        return text;
    }

    public static String jsonGetRequest(String urlQueryString) {
        String json = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlQueryString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
            json = streamToString(inStream); // input stream to string
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you already have an active session in your browser window, therefore, you have all the necessary headers and cookies. But you don't have an active session in the application you're building. So I think you should add some authentication mechanism to your app before calling APIs.

Comment: I have got also 403 Access denied due to 'The owner of this website (apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br) has banned the country or region your IP address is in (UA) from accessing this website.'  so maybe you need to additional header to the  request

Comment: Hey htshame, can you give me an example of authentication mechanism that I could use?

Comment: Sergey, I don't think this will be a problem, I'm in Brazil, here the API works fine

Comment: I just realized you have a `token` parameter in your url. By any chance, is that your api key?

Comment: Yeah, it's mine. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is blocking the default Java useragent. You need to set a different one via `setRequestProperty`:

```java
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","useragent");
```

Note that it doesn't matter what the agent actually is, just as long as it is not the default one. 
With the useragent of "a":

[image: json]